# Recognize font from this website?

Tags: fonts

I am hoping someone can recognize the font on the website http://www.dineinkelowna.com - the word "Kelowna" behind the "Dine In" is the font I'm looking for. I did this design a while ago and can't figure out what font it is (source files are gone). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: you could try and upload an image here: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: no, identifont. myfonts only works with very readable text, that sample is half covered and too close to the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insignia.

http://www.linotype.com/45702/InsigniaStdRoman-product.html

Type Kelowna in the "sample text" box. It's spot on.

Use Identifont for text like that. http://www.identifont.com/

Comment: That's a great resource, thank you so much!